# What is pair[] getAll() mean in LRU cache?

Tags: java

I am studing the LRU cache algorithms. I have a question about the pair[] getAll(), which is the method defined in cache interface.

```
  interface Cache<K extends Comparable, V> {
  V get(K obj);  
  void put(K key, V obj); 
  void put(K key, V obj, long validTime);
  void remove(K key); 
  Pair[] getAll();
  int size();
}
```

Inside the LRUCache class. the method is implemented.

```
  public Pair[] getAll() {
     Pair p[] = new Pair[m_maxSize];
     int count = 0;
     synchronized(m_listLock) {
        Item cur = m_start.next;
        while(cur!=m_end) {
           p[count] = new Pair(cur.key, cur.value);
           ++count;
           cur = cur.next;
        }
     }
     Pair np[] = new Pair[count];
     System.arraycopy(p, 0, np, 0, count);
     return np;
  }
```

As you can see, I am curious why and how the pair[] can be used before getAll() method? and Why is it used?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests `getAll()` will return an array of all the items(key-value pairs) from the cache. Here `key-value` has been abstracted as a `Pair` which is similar to `Map.Entry` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: Thanks for the replying. So, this actually return a array called pair, and the pair[] is not just arrary, but include a key-value relationship like Entryset. I  Have not see arrary used to decorate method, quite interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @James, if my post answers your query, then upvoting or choosing this as an answer would definitely help :)